# Is there anyway to open a Jupyter notebook file with python and append lines of code to it ( Remove old variables and add new ones dynamically)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

### Change Jupyter notebook file variables with python code

I already have a  Jupyter notebook file with some default variables. I want to run it but with dynamic variables. User will input in django template some variables. I need to post those variables data to the django view and run the jupyter notebook file with the dynamic variables the user had input. Should I open the jupyter, find those variables and change them, or there is other ways to do that ?

Comment: Yes, jupyter notebooks are just text files, stored on the box, where the jupyter web-app is running. You just need to ssh there, and then do whatever you fancy. If you don't know how/where - ask your platform administrator.

Comment: While directly editing the json of the notebook file is possible, if you want a nice way to incorporate variables into Jupyter notebooks and trigger them to run with those changes, you may wish to check out [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). Alternatively, you may find it easier to use [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) in your toolchain  to avoid the json and use easier to edit text.

Comment: thank you, I will try that and let you know